# Struts 2 : There is no Action mapped for namespace [/]

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, action-mapping

I am new to Struts 2 and I have been following a video tutorial on Struts 2(Koushik). I have created the Struts.xml, the action class and JSPs as same as created in the tutorial. But it gives the following exception.

**Exception:**

```
Jan 13, 2014 9:30:48 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [getTutorial] associated with context path [/Struts2Starter]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**TutorialAction.java (Action class that I'm using)**

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.action;

public class TutorialAction {


    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("Hello from execute");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

**Project structure**

[image: Structure of the application]

success.jsp and error.jsp are normal jsp files with some text. I did a lot of things to resolve this issue by googling. But nothing didn't solve this. Please let me know if anyone knows what's behind this. I highly appreciate it. :)

Comment: Change `Struts.xml` to `struts.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleksandr M. It worked like a charm!!! :)

Comment: Renaming `Struts.xml` naming convention to `struts.xml` will work.

Answer (score 1):

The message from error clearly says that

> no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [getTutorial]
> associated with context path [/Struts2Starter]

This means that **action configuration is not available at runtime**. Check out the [config-browser](http://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) plugin to debug configuration issues.

To map correctly url to the action two parameters are required: the action name and namespace.

Struts loads xml configuration on startup and it should know the location of the `struts.xml`. By default it's looking on classpath to find a file with known name like `struts.xml`. Then it parses document and creates a runtime configuration. This configuration is used to find appropriate configuration element for the action url. If no such element is found during request, the 404 error code is returned with the message: **`There is no Action mapped for namespace and action name`**.

Also this message contains a namespace and action names used to find the action config. Then you can check your configuration settings in `struts.xml`. Sometimes the action name and namespace, stored in [`ActionMapping`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapping.html) point to the wrong action. These values are determined by the [`ActionMapper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) which could have different implementation, used by plugins.

There's also another setting that might affect this mapper and mapping, but the point is the same if you get this message then URL is used didn't map any action config in runtime configuration. If you can't realize which URL you should use, you might try [config-browser](http://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) plugin to see the list of URLs available to use.

Comment: I already tried that Roman C. But the same exception occurs. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway.

Comment: @AmilaFonseka It seems you didn't, because you still have the same exception. mark this answer as accepted and upvote it if you want to make thanks.

Comment: Same here, no matter what I do, it's not working at all! Couldn't even find any single tutorial for this fix.

Comment: @Superman I don't understand why this comment? The answer is 10 years old and it is still correct. If you have a question then post it as [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

change your `Struts.xml` and put `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />` in `struts.xml`  `Development mode or devMode` it  enables extra debugging and helps indebugging
            try below code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>

         <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

         <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">
                <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
            </action>

        </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 0):

U just need to check that action name is constant everywhere...i also had same problem i resolved by removing namespace as it is not necessary which i see u have not mentioned and also i had different action name at loginpage.jsp and struts.xml page.. so just see ur action name

Answer (score -1):

Your JSP file should not be under the WEB-INF folder, but should be under the web folder. I've attached an image to show you the right hierarchy.

[Folder System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQedc.png)

Comment: He/she actually translates this to English, though this still isn't a great answer.