# Struts2 -java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher

Tags: java, struts2, classnotfoundexception

I am trying out Struts 2 for first time. I am trying to create a simple Login App. But, I am getting the following Exceptions/Errors:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 16, 2015 12:21:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Sep 16, 2015 12:21:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Loginreg] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I am trying to fix it since evening, but unable to fix it. I have searched few materials , but issue was not solved.  I have installed 6 basic jar files needed for Struts 2 app. Following are my WEB.xml and Struts.xml File..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Login-reg</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my Struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
            value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
            value="ApplicationResources" />

        <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

            <action name="login" method="authenticate"
                class="com.struts2.login.LoginAction">
                <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>

            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have struts jar in classpath

Comment: Unrelated, but note that you appear to be using a fairly old version of Struts 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 requires a certain number of jar files before executing your programs. Make sure you have these included in your editing tools:

```
commons-logging-x.x.jar
freemarker-x.x.jar
xwork-x.x.jar
struts2-core-x.x.jar
ognl-x.x.jar
```

Comment: Can you tell me the procedure to add them . Actually, I have added them, but I guess they are not working properly :(

Comment: If you are using Eclipse then adding the required libraries just in Java Build Path will not work. You have to again add those libraries in Deployment Assembly. Right Click On Project>> Properties >> select Deployment Assemlby . Add required Java Build Path entries by clicking on Add.. button.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After following the procedure you said, I could get rid of this filterDispatcher Exception. However, New errors are coming (but not related to FilterDispatcher ).  I am trying to figure it out . In case I can not figure this out, I will get back to you . Thanks a lot.

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1694)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1209)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)

Comment: This is the new probz I am facing....

Comment: your error seems incomplete i can't figure out

Comment: yup.... the rest of the errors are-----

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)

Comment: Hi, Its done... I could figure out the prob.

Comment: Sep 16, 2015 5:41:57 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Login_Reg/loginauth.action
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [loginauth] associated with context path [/Login_Reg]. - [unknown location]

Comment: Its a new one.. Can you help?

Comment: The above error message is saying that the action class is not available, it means you are did something wrong in your action class configuration, may be it’s a namespace or typo error, just double check the name.

Comment: check this link it may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097002/struts-2-there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace

Comment: <struts>
 <package name="Login_Reg" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="login">
   <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
  </action>
  <action name="welcome">
   <result>pages/welcome.jsp</result>
  </action>
  <action name="loginauth" class="com.struts2.login_reg.LoginAction"  
   <result name="success" type="redirect">
  <param name="location">/welcome</param>
  </result>
   <result name="error">pages/login.jsp</result>
  </action>
 </package>
</struts>

Comment: I m trying to figure it out.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Do me a favor create a new question and post the code checking all this in comment not worthy

Comment: Thanks for your help-- I have posted a new questionp---

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608853/there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace-and-action-name-loginauth-associat

Comment: above mentioned link is for the new question..

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.xml` should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

and copy the below jars in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

```
struts2-core-2.3.32.jar
xwork-core-2.3.32.jar
ognl-3.0.19.jar
freemarker-2.3.22.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
```