# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [loginauth] associated with context path [/Login_Reg]

Tags: java, struts2, action-mapping

```
Sep 16, 2015 6:02:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 2522 ms
Sep 16, 2015 6:02:49 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Login_Reg/loginauth.action
    There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [loginauth] associated with context path [/Login_Reg]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:554)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you help me to fix this problem?

Here is my struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPEstrutsPUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="Login_Reg" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="login">
                <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="welcome">
                <result>pages/welcome.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="loginauth" class="com.struts2.login_reg.LoginAction"      
                <result name="success" type="redirect">
            <param name="location">/welcome</param>
            </result>
                <result name="error">pages/login.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

Comment: You have malformed xml.

Comment: Can  you please explain a lil bit more? How to fix it?

Comment: The `loginauth` `action` tag isn't closed.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting... but, Issue is not solved yet

Comment: Turn on devmode, and check your server's startup log.

Comment: @DaveNewton  devmode is already turned on... ANd , I have copied the whole stacktrace here in the question .

Comment: *Startup* logs, not the stacktrace when you try to access the URL.

Comment: This is just *WARNING* it should not change anything in the application, but you should work hard in the direction to discover the cause of it and remove if it's not required.

Comment: have you try after restarting server?